# Any list/library settings responsible for REST availability?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I'm a power user/business admin of SP2010 Foundation Site and I'm trying to use REST API. Under "https://...../_vti_bin/ListData.svc" I see a complete index of all my lists & libraries. When I sent HTTP request, some respond with proper xml and HTTP 200 status and some just give me status 500:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<code /> 
<message xml:lang="pl-PL">An error occurred while processing this request.</message> 
</error>
```

Comparing the lists, they are pretty similar and I have the same permissions. I'm pretty sure there're no specific settings on the server side.

I will aprreciate any suggestions on what can result in some lists responding and some not.

--------------- EDIT:
Sorry, for the mess, but it turned out that there is a problem on the server side. We work on some wierd version of sharepoint and not all components are installed. However "due to Windows Server Patching (controlled by a different team) parts of the API made it onto the servers" which supposedly resulted in some lists responding to queries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what can help you to troubleshoot issue.

1. If you are passing filters, check columns are present in target list/library.
2. check lists does not have any threshold limit values crossed(items, columns etc)

Also paste your code which you are using to create make http request for one success scenario from where you are getting data and one where you are getting error.

Comment: Hi Siddhart,
thank you for your time.
The thing is, to make request as error-proof as possible, for now I am not passing any filters or any other arguments. I am simply trying to connect and get all the data. 

Working request:

'https://..../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Products'

Not working:

'https://..../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Processes'


I think the threshold limit is not an issue too, because the lists are really small - 672 and 413 elements respectively.